# Linear movement with moveit?

Tags: rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm using moveit and rviz to move my robot.
Anyone knows how can I define a linear movement?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193304/linear-movement-with-moveit?/) by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS-Industrial recently released the 'Cartesian Path Planner Plug-In for MoveIt!' for RViz. That would allow you to plan / play / debug Cartesian paths from within RViz, similar to how the MoveIt plugin works.

Blog posting: [Cartesian Path Planner Plug-In for MoveIt!](http://rosindustrial.org/news/2014/9/5/cartesian-path-planner-plug-in-for-moveit) (it's not a MoveIt plugin, but an RViz plugin).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1